# How to trap input change events but not every keystroke?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple component consisting of an input (jobId) and a span (jobDescription). When the user enters a jobId, the component makes an ajax call to fill in the description. Sounds easy. But here is my problem, the way I wrote it, the component makes a bunch of wasteful calls to lookup the jobDescription with each keypress.

I tried changing the lookup to onBlur instead of onChange, but then I miss the "initial load" (the initial render when the jobId is passed in from the parent). So jobDescription is blank when the form is first opened.

So here is what I need:

1. When the user types in a jobId, lookup the corresponding jobDescription. But not necessarily on every key stroke.
2. When the parent passes in a jobId, it should also lookup the    corresponding jobDescription.

Here is the component as it is now:

```
import React from "react";

type Props = {
    jobId:string,
    onChange:(jobId: string)=>void
}

type State = {
    description:string
}

export default class JobComponent extends React.Component {

    props: Props;
    state: State;

    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            description: ""
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps: Props) {
        if (nextProps.jobId != this.props.jobId) {
            this.loadDescription(nextProps.jobId)
                .then((description)=> {
                    this.setState({description});
                });
        }
    }

    onChangeInternal = (event)=> {
        const jobId = event.target.value;
        this.props.onChange(jobId);
        this.loadDescription(jobId)
            .then((description)=> {
                this.setState({description});
            });
    };

    render() {
        return <div>
            <input className="job-id" value={this.props.jobId} onChange={this.onChangeInternal}/>
            <span className="job-description">{this.state.description}</span>
        </div>;
    }

    loadDescription = (jobId): Promise<string> => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (!jobId) resolve("");
            else
                fetch('/components/job-picker/jobService.jsp?jobId=' + jobId)
                    .then((response) => {
                        return response.json();
                    })
                    .then((job) => {
                        resolve(job.description);
                    });
        });
    };
}
```

And here is a sample for the parent component:

```
import React from "react";
import JobComponent from "./JobComponent";

export default class FormTest extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "Dave",
            jobId: "360107",
            age: 50
        }
    }
    render() {
        const onNameChange = (event)=> {
            this.setState({name: event.target.value});
        };
        const onAgeChange = (event)=> {
            this.setState({age: event.target.value});
        };
        const onJobIdChange = (jobId)=> {
            this.setState({jobId});
        };
        return (
            <div>
                Name<input value={this.state.name} onChange={onNameChange}/><br/>
                JobId<JobComponent jobId={this.state.jobId} onChange={onJobIdChange}/><br/>
                Age<input value={this.state.age} onChange={onAgeChange}/><br/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

So, assuming who understand what I'm trying to do, how would you write this component in React?

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for a particular time before making a request. This is primarily delaying the request and wait for user input. Change your `onChange` handler to something like this

```
onChangeInternal = (event)=> {
    const jobId = event.target.value;
    this.props.onChange(jobId);
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId); // resets the timeout on new input
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      this.loadDescription(jobId)
        .then((description)=> {
            this.setState({description});
        });
    }, 500); //delays request by 500ms. 

};
```

You should also check [Lodash's Debounce.](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#debounce) This will delay the function call for a given time.

Hope this helps!